# BRIDE compile error talkerConfig.h not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After the great talk during ROSCon, I tried to create a node using BRIDE. The creation of the node went well, I generated the C++ code using BRIDE->ROS->Generate C++ code and it worked fine.

The problem I'm having is that when building the project, I get the following error:

```
11:15:39 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sr_talker ****
make all 
make: Warning: File `build/CMakeFiles/CompilerIdC/subdir.mk' has modification time 92 s in the future
Building file: ../ros/src/sr_talker_ros.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"ros/src/sr_talker_ros.d" -MT"ros/src/sr_talker_ros.d" -o "ros/src/sr_talker_ros.o" "../ros/src/sr_talker_ros.cpp"
../ros/src/sr_talker_ros.cpp:5:39: fatal error: sr_talker/sr_talkerConfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ros/src/sr_talker_ros.o] Error 1

11:15:41 Build Finished (took 1s.313ms)
```

As you can see, the sr_talkerConfig.h doesn't seem to be generated during compile. Looking in the console from which I started eclipse (`rosrun bride eclipse`) I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no spawner in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.ProcessFactory.<init>(ProcessFactory.java:39)
at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.ProcessFactory.getFactory(ProcessFactory.java:51)
at org.eclipse.cdt.core.CommandLauncher.execute(CommandLauncher.java:189)
at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.BuildRunnerHelper.build(BuildRunnerHelper.java:238)
at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ExternalBuildRunner.invokeExternalBuild(ExternalBuildRunner.java:128)
at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ExternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(ExternalBuildRunner.java:72)
at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:510)
at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:513)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:422)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.GlobalBuildAction$1.run(GlobalBuildAction.java:180)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 64bits. Tried both the default install (`sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-bride`) and the source install. Also tried different versions of java, just in case. Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62874/bride-compile-error-talkerconfig.h-not-found/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you building the project using rosmake or plain make?

The *Config.h file is generated during the dynamic_reconfigure step. BRIDE only generates the .cfg files.
In the CMakeList.txt the triggers to dynamic_reconfigure should be there, it seems they are not called in your case.

---

Originally posted by [AlexanderBubeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/4926/alexanderbubeck/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2013-05-27**:
OK, building with rosmake instead of standard eclipse build did the trick. The tutorial is misleading as it states to use build project from eclipse which doesn't work the first time.